# Add class on dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a class that when I add it it activates an animation
with the use of ajax i'm creating list of topics  after that i'm trying to add class for each li element with a delay so it looks like every second a new topic is added to the list, but it didn't work.

The css file include slideExpandUp class which does the animation (this work great)

Here's the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  GetTopics();
  AnimateEvent();
});


function GetTopics() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Main/GetTopics',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
      if (data.topics != null) {
        var myTopics = "";

        $.each(data.topics, function (idx, obj) {
          myTopics += "<li class='topic'><a href='#'>" + obj.Topic + "</a></li>";
        });

        $("#topics").append(myTopics);
      }
      else {
        alert("2");
      }
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  })
}

function AnimateEvent() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $("#topics li").each(function () {
      $(this).addClass('slideExpandUp') 
    });
  }, 0);
}
```

To sum up, I need to know how, after creating elements, I'm adding class for each element with a delay between each add.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why not just add the class when you append the new `li`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `setInterval()` method instead :

```
var current_index=0;

setInterval(function () {
  activeNextLi(); 
}, 1000); //1 second

function activeNextLi(){
  if(current_index<$("#topics li").length-1)
    current_index++;
  else
    current_index=0;

  $("#topics li").removeClass('slideExpandUp');
  $("#topics li").eq(current_index).addClass('slideExpandUp')
}
```

That will add class `slideExpandUp` to all the `li` elements every second as the passed parameter `1000` shows.

Hope this helps.

```js
var current_index=0;

setInterval(function () {
  activeNextLi(); 
}, 1000); //1 second

function activeNextLi(){
  if(current_index<$("#topics li").length-1)
    current_index++;
  else
    current_index=0;

  $("#topics li").removeClass('slideExpandUp');
  $("#topics li").eq(current_index).addClass('slideExpandUp')
}
```

```css
.slideExpandUp{
  color:red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id='topics'>
  <li class='slideExpandUp'>topic 1</li>
  <li>topic 2</li>
  <li>topic 3</li>
  <li>topic 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this what i needed i change it a little because i needed to do this only once and in the end every element in the list has the class it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

try to make your event under AnimateEvent function as delegated event like this and use setInterval may be this can help you.

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
function AnimateEvent() {
  setInterval(function () {
    $('body').find("#topics li").each(function () {
      $(this).addClass('slideExpandUp') 
    });
  }, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your case the function `AnimateEvent` doesn't any effect whatsoever because function `GetTopics` is a asynchronous call and it will get finished after some delay in future. While you are calling the `AnimateEvent` before anything added in the DOM.

So, the solution is to pass the function as a callback and call it when you finish your append.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  GetTopics(AnimateEvent); // <---pass the function as callback here.
});


function GetTopics(callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Main/GetTopics',
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: true,
    processData: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.topics != null) {
        var myTopics = "";

        $.each(data.topics, function(idx, obj) {
          myTopics += "<li class='topic'><a href='#'>" + obj.Topic + "</a></li>";
        });

        $("#topics").append(myTopics);
      } else {
        alert("2");
      }
      callback(); //<----call that function here.
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
      alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
  })
}

function AnimateEvent() {
  $("#topics li").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('slideExpandUp')
  });
}
```